# Is it important to fix warnings about martian packets in the kernel ring buffer?

Tags: debian, networking, google-cloud

These are the outputs I see when I run `dmesg`

```
[1373335.656608] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
[1373364.891962] device eth1 entered promiscuous mode
[1374537.599978] IPv4: martian source 10.5.0.2 from 203.115.192.116, on dev eth0
[1374562.256536] device eth1 left promiscuous mode
[1375229.342282] device eth1 entered promiscuous mode
[1376178.967446] device eth0 left promiscuous mode
[1376182.455498] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
```

- Q1) I know that martian packets have source addresses that are using non-routable IPs. This host is a Google compute instance with an ephemeral public IP. What does "martian source 10.5.0.2 from 203.115.192.116" mean ?
- Q2) Should I iptables filter these (for security sake) ?

Answer (score 4):

A packet arriving on an interface is considered "martian" if a hypothetical reply packet would be routed through a different interface. In your case 203.115.192.116 sent a packet to 10.5.0.2, which arrived on your eth0 interface. If 10.5.0.2 is your address, `ip route get 203.115.192.116` correctly reports an interface different from eth0, and you actually intend to do such asymmetric routing, then these martian logs should be disabled like

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/log_martians
```

and `rp_filter` must be disabled as well. Otherwise (and this seems much more probable) there is a routing problem somewhere which should be fixed. If it can't be fixed (quite possible in a hosted cloud environment), you can disable logging altogether like above or drop more selectively by `iptables` (the *filter* chain may be too late for that, though).

Comment: ``$ ip route get 203.115.192.116`` returns eth0 (not asymmetric).

Comment: And still you get martian reports from that IP on eth0? I'm baffled. Is 10.5.0.2 your address at least? Please include the `ll header` line following the martian report and the output of the `ip a`, `ping -c3 203.115.192.116`, `ip route get 203.115.192.116` and `ip neigh show to 203.115.192.116` commands (in this order) into your question.

Answer (score 3):

Martian packets are when an expected local address is seen in that interface (e.g. packets local to the network with a different network of that packet).

While it is not an advised network design, it can happen some networks have "martian" packets by design (e.g. VLANs/physical networks with several logical networks).

If you are using `iptables` in a server, it might not be a bad idea filtering out packets that you should not see.

Note that however, while I would have martian logging in a pre-production setting, I would prefer to not log martian as that usually it generates a lot of logs, and taxes your I/O operations.